# Assigning values to a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am translating some algorithm into C++ (which I wrote in R and already translated into C++ with raw pointers). The problem with the original C++ translation is that it crashes for large matrices and suffers from memory leaks (but is approx 1000 times faster than R which is amazing)... So i try again with vector. Basically I have a matrix with zeroes and ones and want to replace the ones by a number indicating a group. 
A group would be defined by horizontally or vertically connected one-entries.
I do this by building up a matrix of pointers and change the group indices they point to during the process.

The code below is an excerpt.

```
vector<int> groups(vector<int> matrix, int nrow, int ncol) {

    vector<connection> connections;
    vector<int *> pointersToIndices;

    int zeroGroupIndex = 0;
    int* O = &zeroGroupIndex;   
    int currentN = 1;
    int size = nrow * ncol;

    vector<int **> pointerMatrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int** OO = &O;
        pointerMatrix.push_back(OO);
    }


    int col, row, index, leftIndex, upperleftIndex, upperIndex;
    for (col = 0; col < ncol; col++) {
        for (row = 0; row < nrow; row++) {
            index = nrow * col + row;       
            if (matrix[index] != 0) {
                upperIndex = nrow * col + row - 1;
                leftIndex = nrow * (col - 1) + row;
                if (row == 0 || matrix[upperIndex] == 0) {
                    currentN++;
                    matrix[index] = currentN;                   
                    pointersToIndices.push_back(&(matrix[index]));
                    // I assume the following does not do what i intend 
                    pointerMatrix[index] = &pointersToIndices.back();
                }
                else pointerMatrix[index] = pointerMatrix[upperIndex];
                if (col != 0 && matrix[leftIndex] != 0) *pointerMatrix[index] = *pointerMatrix[leftIndex];
            }
        }
    }
....
....
```

Now the problem is that the assignments dont work as I want them to. Especially the line

```
pointerMatrix[index] = &pointersToIndices.back();
```

seems to fail, since at the end of the loop all elements of `pointerMatrix` point to the last entry of `pointersToIndices` and not the correct one.

I hope I could clarify the problem.
Any suggestions?
Thank you very much.

Comment: _"Any suggestions?"_ Yes. Don't use pointers. Also, help yourself and write a good matrix class you can test. Then, use it to do whatever you want to do.

Comment: If you very much concerned about speed you really should layout all the matrix data in one single allocation so the memory is not fragmented. Using a matrix library might help you get the task done faster. For exampl 'Eigen' or boost lib also has 1 or 2 matrix libraries. And also avoid using raw pointers - not a good idea if you are a learner.

Comment: It looks like you have overcomplicated things with unnecessary indirections.

Comment: A pointer into a vector is not valid if a push_back resizes the vector. Why not store indices instead of pointers?

Comment: or use iterators, although you will have to be careful of invalidation

Comment: To add to paddy's comment: why not store coordinates? It's a matrix, after all. It would also eliminate `pointersToIndices`.

Comment: I am not sure If it is enough to store coordinates. I iterate through the original matrix with zeroes and ones and if I find a 1 i need to look at the upper and left neighbours. It is not sufficient to tell them neighbours: Now point to the same index as I do since the neighbours of the neighbours also need to get informed.

Comment: @MikaProuk I didn't really get what you mean, but having a matrix and coordinates is about equivalent to having the address of an element in that matrix, only more readable, intuitive and robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pointerToIndices` will eventually reallocate when it has to grow (after a number of `push_back`s). This invalidates pointers to its elements (such as those taken and stored in the line after the comment), so using them later on is undefined behavior.

I have not fully understood your algorithm, but either ensure that `pointersToIndices` does not reallocate (by reserving enough space beforehand) or refrain from using pointers to its elements. (Or change your algorithm).

Comment: Now. All I did was to change the declaration of `pointersToIndices` to `vector<int *> pointersToIndices(size);` It works. But. I reserve space for millions of values and will not need a fraction of it. Isn't this quite bad?

Comment: @MikaProuk Yes, that sounds suboptimal. There are other data structures that might help you with this though. I suggest you look into [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), which will never invalidate upon appending to (or deleting from) either end. But maybe you can change your algorithm to use matrix/vector indices instead of pointers.

Comment: @MikaProuk Well, it obviously adds some megabytes of runtime memory to your program. Now, you can go with it, or you can do things better by not dealing with pointers so much.